# Return alias field via json using mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongoid(2.6.0) with its alias and this is how my model field looks like

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :n, :as => :name, :type => String
  ....
```

Now I have a controller which finds a place and return the object as json

```
@places = Place.find({some query})
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @places }
end
```

Now when I do

```
JSON.parse(response.body)
```

My response contains the field as "n" and not as "name".

Is there a way I can ask mongoid to return me the alias name and not the actual name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can try overriding **serializable_hash** method. Just add something like this in your model.

```
def serializable_hash(options)
  original_hash = super(options)
  Hash[original_hash.map {|k, v| [self.aliased_fields.invert[k] || k , v] }]
end
```

Comment: I would advise you to put it in an ActiveSupport::Concern and to include it in all your mongoid models